# Instagram Basic Display API - Can't generate access token

Tags: instagram, access-token, instagram-api

I can't get access token for the Instagram Basic Display API.
[image: Screenshot of Step 1 of getting Instagram Basic Display API access token]

here when I press Generate Token, popup comes up and here it is:

[image: Error message of popup]

I've tried adding another test user, I've tried waiting for hours and nothing happens, it's all the same

Have you seen anything like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this problem as well. In my case, my ip must have been flagged for excessive use or something. Because I was able to generate tokens after switching to another internet connection (using my phone instead of my home Wi-Fi)